# NSObject is undefined (objective c)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode3.2

This is more then likely a very simple question but I am completely stumped by it (and more then a little embarrassed by the situation).  I have the following code in a command line utility in xCode:

```
#include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

}
```

When I build the project I get an error that "'NSFileManager' is undeclared".  If I add the line:

```
#include <Foundation/Foundation.h>
```

my error count jumps from 3 to 3951 with all of the errors in the file "NSObjCRuntime.h".  I don't think there is anything wrong with the code, but do I have something in the programing environment set up wrong?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also forgot your auto release pool, I don't think you should do such stuff yourself when you don't know what you are doing, and just let Xcode do the hard work for you.

There should ben a template available in the new project window for Foundation based command line tools.

Comment: When I created the project I didn't realize there was a difference between core foundation tools and foundation tools (honestly didn't eve notice the option).

Answer (score 2):

Those single quotes are not valid. Try this:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
```

Comment: Single quotes were an artifact of me not using stackoverflow's markdown wrong.  Post updated.